# cell text looking like its being highlighted on long press for moveable table cells

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, tableview

**** updated with screen grab ****

I followed this tutorial on how to incorporate a long press on a table cell to move them around. [(*tutorial*)](http://www.raywenderlich.com/63089/cookbook-moving-table-view-cells-with-a-long-press-gesture). I got everything working the way I wanted it to, but the first time you selected a cell and move it, all the cell text is set to black, and it should just blend in with the background of the cell, but instead the text is black with a lighter grey colored box around the text. This only happens the first time I selected the cell, after that it just shows a blackened cell. Any idea what may cause this? It almost looks as though the text is selected or highlighted from the long press, but why does it only happen the first time?

[image: screeb grab if the "ghosting"]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just hiding the text using alpha when selected and turning the alpha back to 1 on release.

on selected

```
cell.detailTextLabel.alpha = 0;
cell.textLabel.alpha = 0;
```

on release

```
cell.detailTextLabel.alpha = 1;
cell.textLabel.alpha = 1;
```